# What is the streaming log data latency between AWS & Google cloud services?

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-bigquery, amazon-dynamodb, google-cloud-dataflow, amazon-kinesis

Has anyone had experience with:

1. Sending streamed/micro-batched log data from Amazon to BigQuery to process and can shed light on any latency issue?
2. Sending (micro-batched) logs from Google DataFlow to Amazon (Kinesis / S3 / DynamoDB)

Can someone provide info on latency?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In question 1, I believe you're interested in BigQuery ingestion latency. Per [Streaming Data into BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery#dataavailability), *Streamed data is available for real-time analysis within a few seconds of the first streaming insertion into a table.* This latency is low, but it will probably dominate whatever latency you have due to raw network communication from an Amazon cluster to BigQuery API.

In question 2, you're probably interested in the latency of Dataflow itself - assuming data arrives into a Dataflow streaming pipeline, e.g. via PubSub, at real time, and you're processing it and ultimately writing to Amazon, and you're interested in how quickly the results come back.

This depends highly on the windowing structure of your pipeline (e.g., if you window data into 5-minute windows, data will be buffered accordingly).  If you don't do any windowing at all, latency introduced by Dataflow itself should be low (sub-second). For details of how that is achieved, you can consult [the MillWheel paper](http://research.google.com/pubs/pub41378.html) on which Dataflow's streaming engine is based.

Comment: Thx for your response.

Comment: I am actually wondering if processing data (no windowing)  that was originated on Amazon cloud, on Google cloud, and then sending it back to Amazon would pose noticeable latency unacceptable by realtime use cases (lets say up-sale recommendation on a webpage for ex.), the concern being mainly around the round trip transition time between the 2 clouds.

Comment: The network latency would probably be determined mostly by which region of Amazon's and Google's clouds you're in, and I'd suggest to just measure it by hand and see if it's good enough. Dataflow would usually introduce a small amount of additional latency, though it is not technically a hard real time system and occasional latency hiccups are possible.