# Google Cloud Dataflow latency for real-time processing

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

How low can we expect the latency from Dataflow to be in cases where we just do a simple transform on a high-traffic Google Dataflow cluster, and each “data point” is small.

We’re planning on using the Sessions windowing strategy with a gap duration of 3 seconds, if that’s relevant.

Is it realistic that the time from a data point gets into Dataflow until we have a result to output can be less than 2 seconds? Less than 1 second?

Comment: I'm confused: you want to window by sessions with a gap duration of 3 seconds, but you also want to emit results <1s after a data point arrives - these requirements seem contradictory, because until at least 3 seconds elapse you can not be sure that you've observed the whole session. Can you clarify?

Comment: We want to compare two streams of data and once we find that there's a match, we don't need to consider the rest of the data.

Comment: I see. So e.g. if you have a session of events A, B, C, D for a given key, then you want the GBK to be triggered as soon as possible after each of them arrives, and have the ParDo process respectively A, AB, ABC, and ABCD?

Comment: Yes, but starting with ABC. (First trigger is "AfterPane.elementCountAtLeast(3)")

Comment: I see. Then you're interested in latency introduced by the execution engine itself. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34279297/what-is-the-streaming-log-data-latency-between-aws-google-cloud-services which asks a similar question.

Comment: Thank you! So latency can be really low as long as we don't do too complicated calculations in Dataflow.

Comment: Correct, it can be very low.

Comment: I would also like to use dataflow to transform messages from a third party provider via pub sub and I'm looking for any performance statistics or if that is a good idea in general

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We have been running benchmarks for our application flow using a test harness but then reverted to benchmarking the current out-of-the-box Google-supplied PubSub to PubSub template flow (see: https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/templates/overview, although not listed here - you can create it from the Console).

Our test harness generated and sent millions of JSON-formatted messages of a few hundred bytes with timestamps and compared the latencies at either end. 
Very Simply:

**Test Publisher -> PubSub -> Data Flow -> PubSub -> Test Subscriber.**

For single instance publisher and subscribers we varied the message rates and experimented with the windowing and Trigger Strategies to see if we could improve the average latency but typically weren't able to improve much beyond **1.7 seconds** end-to-end for 1,500 - 2000 messages per second (our typical workload).

We then removed Dataflow from the equation and just hooked up the publisher to the subscriber directly and saw latencies typically around **20-30 milliseconds** for identical message rates.

Reverting to using the standard PubSub to PubSub Data flow template we saw end-to-end latencies similar to that of our application data flow of around **1.5 - 1.7 seconds.**

We sampled the timestamps at various points in the pipeline and written the values to a number custom metrics and have seen that the average latency for adding the message to the initial PCollection from the PubSubIO.Read was around **380msec**, but the minimum was as low as **25msec**, we ignored the higher values because of the startup overheads. But it seems that there was an overhead that we were unable to influence.

The windowing strategy we tried looked like this:

```
    Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options);
    /*
     * Attempt to read from PubSub Topic
     */
    PCollectionTuple feedInputResults =
            p.apply(feedName + ":read", PubsubIO.readStrings().fromTopic(inboundTopic))
            .apply(Window.<String>configure()
                .triggering(Repeatedly
                    .forever(AfterWatermark.pastEndOfWindow()
                            .withEarlyFirings(
                                    AfterProcessingTime
                                            .pastFirstElementInPane()
                                            .plusDelayOf(Duration.millis(windowDelay)))
                                            // Fire on any late data
                                            .withLateFirings(AfterPane.elementCountAtLeast(windowMinElementCount))))
                    .discardingFiredPanes())
            .apply(feedName + ":parse", ParDo.of(new ParseFeedInputFn())
                        .withOutputTags(validBetRecordTag,
                        // Specify the output with tag startsWithBTag, as a TupleTagList.
                        TupleTagList.of(invalidBetRecordTag)));
```

Comment: Windowing is only needed if you're doing aggregations. If all you want to do is forward Pub/Sub to Pub/Sub, you should not need any windowing.

Comment: Agreed. We have a pipeline that does aggregations and outputs to a number of sinks. Part of the study was to assess the determinism of the end-to-end latency. The consensus is that if it's an issue then it might be prudent to choose a different runner. It's not an issue for us.