# Real time transformations from/to pubsub and websocket push to client

Tags: websocket, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-pubsub

I need to get some real time data from a third party provider, transform them and push the to the browser via websockets.

The whole procedure should not take more than 200ms from the time I received the data till the time the browser gets them.

I am thinking in using pub/sub to dataflow to pub/sub again where a websocket server will subscribe and push the messages to the browsers.

Is this approach correct or dataflow is not designed for something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dataflow is designed for reliable streaming aggregation and analytics and is not designed for guaranteed sub-second latencies through the system.  The core primitives like windowing and triggering allow for reliable processing of streams over defined windows of data despite late data and potential machine or pipeline errors.  The main use case we have optimized for is for example, aggregating and outputting statistics over a stream of data, outputting reliable statistics for each window while doing logging to disk for fault-tolerance and waiting if necessary before triggering, to accommodate late data.  As such, what we have not optimized for is the end-to-end latency you require.

Comment: I see, is there anything else in google cloud that can be used for this scenario? I suppose I would still use pub/sub but for in memory transformations what should I use?

Comment: And say it is OK to have 600ms of latency. Is this approach still wrong. Are there any performance statistics?

Comment: Hmmm in this post they say that dataflow is low latency if no windowing is applied http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34279297/what-is-the-streaming-log-data-latency-between-aws-google-cloud-services

Comment: also this pipeline will transform the messages one to one. No need for windowing as there will be no aggregations

Comment: @chchrist depending on how complex your transformations are, you can simply perform the computation on [App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/writing-and-responding-to-pub-sub-messages) virtual machines, or even on [Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/tutorials/pubsub) as the [Pub/Sub APIs](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/libraries) can be called from any vm. If you know that Dataflow meets your needs, I recommend testing it to see if it aligns with your latency requirements.

Comment: @Jordan yes I am doing a spike at the moment. I will post my findings here. Thank you for the suggestions. Didn't know about google functions! very interesting!